# Unable to run FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-5.6

Here is my query .

```
 SELECT user_record.password,user_addresses.street 
 FROM `user_record` 
 FULL OUTER JOIN `user_addresses` 
     ON user_record.id=user_addresses.user_id 
 ORDER by user_record.id
```

here is the error which is happening when i run my query in Phpmyadmin .

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN `user_addresses` ON user_record.id=user_addresses.user_id ORDER by us' at line 1
```

Comment: Can there be an address with a `user_id` that doesn't exists in `user_record`? If not, you could do with a `LEFT` join instead.

Comment: MySQL still doesn't support full outer joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Full outer join` is not supported. If you look at:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

there is only `LEFT` and `RIGHT` outer join. You can however mimic `FULL OUTER` with a `UNION` between `LEFT` and `RIGHT`:

```
SELECT user_record.id AS user_id, 
       user_record.password, user_addresses.street 
FROM `user_record` 
LEFT JOIN `user_addresses` 
    ON user_record.id = user_addresses.user_id 

UNION

SELECT user_addresses.user_id, 
       user_record.password, user_addresses.street 
FROM `user_record` 
RIGHT JOIN `user_addresses` 
    ON user_record.id = user_addresses.user_id 

ORDER BY user_id ;
```

You have to include `user_record.id / user_addresses.user_id` in your select clause to be able to order by it.

Comment: Thnx. Made a minor correction as well.

Comment: There are more efficient ways.  Note that `LEFT` and `RIGHT` both include the intersection, thereby requiring the `UNION DISTINCT` that you implicitly specified.  (I would make this a "Dup" question if I had the energy to find _all the times this question has been answered_.)